# Cannot deserialize object in django rest framework

Tags: django-rest-framework

I'm closely reading http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers and attempting to implement a basic deserializer. I'm somewhat perplexed as my experimental code is resulting in random results which make little sense.

I have a simple django model:

```
class ArticleType(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=15)

class Article(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=80)
    body = models.TextField()
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    published = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    children = models.ManyToManyField('self')
    article_type = models.ForeignKey(ArticleType)
```

And I have a simple deserializer:

```
class ArticleSerializer(ModelSerializer):

    article_type = serializers.CharField(max_length=15)
    children = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(many=True)

    class Meta:

        model = Article
        fields = ('id', 'featured','published','body','title','children','article_type')
```

In the django shell I run the following:

```
>>> aData = {'id':3,'featured':True,'published':True, 'body':'This is some body text!', 'title':'This is a title!', 'children':[2,3], 'article_type':'Topic'}
>>> aS = ArticleSerializer(data=aData)
```

Which yields:

```
>>> aS.is_valid() 
True
>>> aS.data
{'featured': False, 'published': False, 'body': u'', 'title': u'', 'children': [], 'a_type': u''}
```

From this I have several questions.

1. Why has the data been changed?
2. If the data is invalid, why is the `.is_valid()` method returning true?
3. The documentation is vague on where I am to implement the transformation from CharField with length 15 to actually return the ArticleType instance in my article_type field.

NOTE: The article table is populated with a few dummy articles.

Answer (score 0):

The data hasn't been changed. Those are your defaults as specified in the model. It's your serializer definition that causes the `.is_valid` to return true.

I think you want to define it like this:

```
class ArticleTypeSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    model = models.ArticleType
    fields= ('id', 'name',)

class ArticleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    article_type = ArticleTypeSerializer

    class Meta:
        model = models.Article
        fields = ('id', 'featured','published','body','title','children','article_type',)
```

Also, I'm pretty sure that you want to add `blank=True` to your definition of the children in the model as otherwise every article has children, which have children, which have children, ad infinitum.

One thing I'm not sure about is what the behaviour should be when deserializing M2M fields. Normally django requires you to save the (in your case) Article and then add the children. The serializer doesn't actually do the saving so it wont be able to populate the children. That is the topic for another question however.